# How do I encode angle brackets in servicestack json response

Tags: servicestack, servicestack-text

I have a customer who wants to ensure that responses from our JSON web service do not contain HTML.  So instead of returning a string containing angle brackets they want encoded angle brackets.

Two questions:

- if I return content type application/json do I need to do this?
- how can I do this globally in ServiceStack?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> if I return content type application/json do I need to do this?

You should always return a JSON Mime Type like `application/json` for JSON Responses (ServiceStack automatically does this for you).

> how can I do this globally in ServiceStack?

Support for Escaping HTML Chars was just added in [this commit](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Text/commit/f1608c237860abeced76d8fbc88680e9aed62cde) which will let you globally escape HTML chars into unicode notation with:

```
JsConfig.EscapeHtmlChars = true;
```

This change is available from v4.5.7+ that's now [available on MyGet](http://docs.servicestack.net/myget).

Comment: Thanks for the response.  Do you have any thoughts or suggestions of where to read to determine how serious it is to only send the correct content-type and not escape the HTML?

Comment: @USER9 Setting the content-type isn't relevant, your Customer in all likely hood wants to escape HTML Chars contained in JSON responses, so you'll need to escape it.